# Библиотеки по работе с графами на C#

Tags: c#, библиотеки, графы, lib

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какие-то готовые библиотеки с алгоритмами на графах ? Интересуют: поиск в глубину, в ширину, поиск минимального остова, кратчайшие расстояния между вершинами и т.д.

Comment: Алгоритм Флойда на примере JS https://jsfiddle.net/33geek/c9jazrws/1/

Comment: https://github.com/rhishi/QuickGraph

Comment: Фишка в том, что граф еще можно хранить разными способами и для каждого из них алгоритм будет реализован по своему. А вообще в `.Net` есть стандартные классы коллекций `Queue<T>` и `Stack<T>`, используя которые обход графа в ширину и в глубину реализуются достаточно просто